Can we get the bound of $S_n(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ under assumption $x_k>0,\forall 1\le k\le n$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=1$?
For a square with side length 1 I considered the following graph: First I divide the right side into $n$ parts and denote whose length are $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k$. Then following the picture we get corresponding segments (and the length of them are $l_1,l_2,\cdots,l_n$). 
We can get the exact form of $l_k:$ $$l_k=2\sin\frac{\arctan\frac{x_k}{1-(x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1})(x_1+\cdots+x_k)}}{2},\quad x_0=0,1\le k\le n,$$
but it is not concise enough. So I try to use equivalent infinitesimal:
$$l_k\sim\arctan\frac{x_k}{1-(x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1})(x_1+\cdots+x_k)}\sim\frac{x_k}{1-(x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1})(x_1+\cdots+x_k)}.$$
Thus I get the following sum relevant to $\sum_{k=1}^n l_k$:
$$S_n(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{1-(x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1})(x_1+\cdots+x_k)}.$$
Question:$\quad$Can we get good upper bound and lower bound of $S_n(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)?$
My Attempt: I tried setting $\displaystyle x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=\frac{1}{n}$,then I get
$$S_n(n^{-1},\cdots,n^{-1})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-\frac{k(k-1)}{n^2}}$$
which is unbounded.

If I understand well, you want to get the bounds of $$P_n(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum_{k=1}^nl_k$$ However, you think the formula of $P_n$ is quite complex and you approximate it by $S_n(x_1,...,x_n) $ and then find the bounds of $S_n$? But, it seems to me that it's easier to find directly the bounds of $P_n$!

Actually I want to find the bound of $S_n$ here and here I just give $P_n$ as the background of $S_n$.

@IIU The infimum of $S_n$ is $1$ when $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_{n-1} \to 0$? And $S_n$ has no upper bound e.g. $x_1 \to 1$?
